# Jquery mobile page not expanding with collapsible

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile app, and in it there is a collapsible div.

When I click this collapsible, it opens, but the page height stays at 100%, meaning i can't scroll down and see the stuff inside it.

I thought jquery mobile was meant to adjust the page height when something like this is opened?

```
<div id="hints" class="main" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="content" id="content">
         <h2>Hints &amp; Tips</h2>
         <p>Helping you get the most out of ARMA 3</p>
         <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-content-theme="e">
             <h4>Launch Paramaters</h4>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would really like a CSS fix rather than a JS one if possible, as this shouldn't require JS.

I have tried:

```
* {
    min-height:100% !important;
}

* {
    min-height:auto !important;
}
```

The CSS that appears to affect it is:

```
.ui-panel{
border:1px solid #333;
background:#111;
color:#fff;
font-weight:bold;
text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #000;
background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from( #3c3c3c ),to( #111 ));
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient( #3c3c3c,#111 );
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient( #3c3c3c,#111 );
background-image:-ms-linear-gradient( #3c3c3c,#111 );
background-image:-o-linear-gradient( #3c3c3c,#111 );
background-image:linear-gradient( #3c3c3c,#111 )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out the problem, it was due to this code:

```
.ui-panel{
    border:1px solid #333;
}
```

If anyone can explain why this causes an issue, it would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is strange, this shouldn't happen.
Have you modified any CSS or style property of your page ? (like defining a fixed height etc.)

Comment: Updated question with the css i have changed. Its all stuff that shouldnt affect the page height though

Comment: Have you tried removing those CSS lines to see if the problem comes from it ?

Comment: I have worked through commenting bits out, and the code above is the part that causes this issue